# Querying distinct pairs of ids

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

This query is successfully pulling pairs of ids for rows in table taxi_lines where a driver appears with more than one open assignment (eg in 2 taxis at once).

My problem is that it pulls each pair of ids in both orders (eg 500 and 509 and then 509 and 500).

[image: data]

I tried adding `DISTINCT(CONCAT(tl1.id,tl2.id)),`  and also `GROUP BY id1, id2` but these did not achieve unique pairs.

Here is the working query that gets the data above.  How do I refine to get unique pairs?

```
SELECT tl1.id AS id1, tl2.id AS id2
FROM taxi_lines tl1
JOIN taxi_lines tl2 ON tl1.driver = tl2.driver
AND tl1.id != tl2.id
AND tl1.driver > 0
WHERE tl1.end =  '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND   tl2.end =  '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: add `AND tl1.id > tl2.id` remove `AND tl1.id != tl2.id`  This works becuase the join tl1.driver=tl2.driver gets you the like drivers but you only want once instance since != gives you both, > or < will give you just one depending on which one you want in what id field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `AND tl1.id != tl2.id` with `AND tl1.id > tl2.id`

Answer (score 1):

Try something simple like:

```
AND t11.id > tl2.id
```

This will only return rows where the first id is larger than the second.  It will get rid of half your rows.

Answer (score 0):

what affect does this have

```
SELECT distinct 
      case when tl1.id < tl2.id then tl1.id else tl2.id  end as id1,
      case when tl1.id < tl2.id then tl2.id else tl1.id  end as id2

FROM taxi_lines tl1
JOIN taxi_lines tl2 ON tl1.driver = tl2.driver
AND tl1.id != tl2.id
AND tl1.driver > 0
WHERE tl1.end =  '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND   tl2.end =  '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: That result is exactly the same as the current query

Comment: sorry I hit return for the next line and it posted, I was too quick

Comment: Thank you.  That's closer but allows rows where id is same eg both tl1 and tl2 = 504.  Answer above yours seems to do the trick.